# Is there a way to prevent SSH from lowercasing the hostname?

Tags: ssh

I'm using an SSH config file with a [ProxyCommand](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand) to hop through a bastion host to my target host. Specifically, the `ProxyCommand` uses a cloud service CLI that takes the hostname / user / port I originally passed, looks them up in a database, and connects me to the host through their bastion. It essentially looks like this:

```
Host host-*
  ProxyCommand /bin/the-cli %h %r %p
```

The problem is that the database of target hostnames is case-sensitive, i.e. `host-XyZ`, but SSH always turns the hostname I originally entered (`%h`) into a lowercase string. So the end result is something like:

```sh
$ ssh host-XyZ

Bastion service: there are no targets with name 'xyz'
```

Can I prevent SSH from doing this? I don't see any documentation of where the remote hostname is being converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use %n instead. Per ssh_config manual

```
%n    The original remote hostname, as given on the command line.
```

OpenSSH lowercases %h, which cannot be disabled.

[13f97b228](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/commit/?id=13f97b2286142fd0b8eab94e4ce84fe124eeb752) circa 2014  changed something to do with CanonicalizeHostname and ssh_config parsing. It also does a lowercase on the host string. Presumably to allow case insensitive substitution before resolving names.

DNS is supposed to be more or less case-insensitive, which is why they can away with this.